# Is it possible to plot array data in imshow with a Y-axis that starts off linear but changes to non-linear steps towards the end

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

Firstly, a big thanks to everyone who responds to these questions. I've made it this far without having to ask a question because I find that someone before me has inevitably encountered the same issue.

However, I find myself with a question that I've not been able to locate. I would like to plot a 2D array within `imshow` that started off with a linear Y-axis, which I have had to offset and adjust and is now non-linear after a certain point. Is this possible?

- see below for a chart and example.

The orange line is the original Y-axis step which has a linear and regular step.
The blue line has been corrected with an offset and a varying step change towards the end. As seen it is linear up to a point before deviating to a non-linear step at the end.

[image: Original Y-axis vs new Y-axis]

I am using `extent` to set the bounds of the axes and as I understand it `imshow` will plot the data with a regular and linear step between the start and end points. I would like to fix the new (blue) Y-axis reference to the data to be plotted so that the data is presented at the correct position with respect to the Y-Axis value.

As an example I have the following code:

```
testData = np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]])

x_axisTest = [1,2,3,4]
y_axisTest = [2,4,8,12]

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax1.imshow(testData, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.jet, origin='upper',
                 aspect='auto', # vmin = 20, vmax = 60,
                 extent =[x_axisTest[0], x_axisTest[3], y_axisTest[3], 
                                y_axisTest[0]])
```

[image: example plot]

As seen the data is linearly plotted even though the Y-axis step changes from 2 (2,4...) to 4 (...8, 12). What I would like is the data to be interpreted or stretched/compressed between Y-axis values 4 to 12 based on the new step value.

I've been looking into resampling the data which is maybe the preferred option but again I'm not sure how best to apply this and ensure I keep the Y-axis matched with the data. My concern is that I may also shift the linear portion of the data. I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: `pcolormesh` allows you to specify the y (and x) co-ordinate with variable spacing.  I almost never use `imshow`: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html

Comment: Perfect, thank you @JodyKlymak, it took a little while to configure the setting for pcolormesh but it is exactly what I was afer.